# Using external variable leads to unexpected object

Tags: terraform

I would like to get a token from a website then use the token in subsequent resources.  I'm using the `external` provider to get the token from a bash script, then use it in later stages:

```
data "external" "token" {
  program = ["sh", "./token.sh"]

  query = {
    api_key = var.api_key
  }
}
```

and `token.sh` looks like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
####################
set -e
TOKEN=`curl -X POST <some url>`
jq -n --arg token "$TOKEN" '{"token":$token}'
```

To acces the `$TOKEN`, I'm using `data.external.token`. I'm getting error: `data.external.token is object with 5 attributes`

I tried doing just `TOKEN='FOO'` in the script and got the same error so I don't think my curl string was the problem. I'm not seeing why the script wouldn't work... Also, is there any good way to debug terraform especially run time variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with this:

> Also, is there any good way to debug terraform especially run time variables?

Yes, you can use Terraform outputs for debugging. For example:

```
output "token_output" {
  value = data.external.token
}
```

Will output something like this:

```
token_output = {
  "id" = "-"
  "program" = tolist([
    "sh",
    "./token.sh",
  ])
  "query" = tomap({
    "api_key" = "foo"
  })
  "result" = tomap({
    "token" = "some token"
  })
  "working_dir" = tostring(null)
}
```

I think this explains why do you get the following error:

```
data.external.token is object with 5 attributes
```

What you are lookin for is the `result` attribute (which is also documented in the [attribute references](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source#attributes-reference)). You can reference it as such:

```
output "result" {
  value = data.external.token.result
}
```

For further debugging, besides of outputs, you can use [`terraform console`](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/console) command as well. This will start a REPL, where you can see the content of your resources from your state.